# need help with permutations problem

Tags: combinatorics

just started permutations and combinations in my class and needed help understanding this question: how many different ways are there to get from time A to tile I without getting visiting a tile more than once if only horizontal and vertical movements are allowed.

[image]

Comment: The answer is 12:
ABCFI,
ABCFEHI,
ABCFEDGHI,
ABEFI,
ABEHI,
ABEDGHI,
ADGHI,
ADEHI,
ADGHEFI,
ADGHEBCFI,
ADEFI,
ADEBCFI. First, you can start by looking at all paths starting with AB. Starting with AB you can go to ABC or ABE. Then you can easily list all possible paths starting with AB, and you can count 6 possible paths. The same for AD (by symmetry), hence the answer is 12.

Comment: Strange question to give to someone just starting on permutations and combinations, where no formula can be applied. Are you sure you have reproduced the question correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem falls under the category of [self-avoiding walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk), which has no closed form expression. Closed form expressions of the number of paths exist for North-East paths on this *lattice grid*, i.e. if you can only move up and right.

So if you're expecting a **proper** formula that just takes in the number of letters on each side of the square, then you're out of luck. The only "formula" is through actual computation, which is the like saying
$ (a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b) $ rather than $ (a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab $

**tl:dr** replace the letters with co-ordinates and you end up with a problem not solved analytically. You can only do this by hand, no formula.